# Create marker icon based on HTML code for OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript

Is there any way that I can create a marker in OpenLayers with an HTML icon?

Example in Mapbox:

```
 marker.setIcon(
       L.divIcon({
            className: 'map_primary_marker_container',
            html: "<div class='map_primary_marker'>TEXT</div><div class='map_primary_marker_bottom'></div>",
            iconSize: [160, 50],
            iconAnchor: [80, 40]
       })
 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found myself a solution, it's a tricky one but if anyone has a better idea please answer.

```
//options object
var options = {
        className: 'map_primary_marker_container',
        html: "<div class='map_primary_marker'>TEXT</div><div class='map_primary_marker_bottom'></div>",
        iconSize: [160, 50],
        iconAnchor: [80, 40]
   };

// create a container for the html code and set the properties
var div             = document.createElement('div');
div.className       = options.className;
div.style.position  = 'absolute';
div.style.width     = options.iconSize[0] + 'px';
div.style.height    = options.iconSize[1] * 10 + 'px';
div.innerHTML       = options.html;
var element         = document.body.appendChild(div);

// generate an encoded picture from the element
html2canvas(element,{
    onrendered: function (canvas){

        setTimeout(function () {
            marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
                image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                    anchor: [options.iconAnchor[0], options.iconAnchor[1]],
                    anchorXUnits: 'pixels',
                    anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                    opacity: 1,
                    src: canvas.toDataURL()
                }))
            }));
        }, 50);
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
    }
});
```